# How to add/maintain line break at end of file while saving in VIM

Tags: vim

This feature is one of the concerns while editing others projects, editors like textmate and sublime I believe add line break for last line, but when I edit end portions of a file with vim and save it I sometimes forget to add the final line break.

So, how do I automate this and make sure files always have at least one new line at the end.

Comment: Hmm, I've tested vim and, if open a file and force its writing, last newline is always added. Do you have specific options which prevent vim against this fix?

Comment: @Netch I've checked `.vimrc` I do not have any such options, I'd like to know how to explicitly tell VIM to add new lines at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't remember if there is solution for this build in vim. Check below snippet. It will add empty line at the end of file.

```
function! AddLastLine()
    if getline('$') !~ "^$"
        call append(line('$'), '')
    endif
endfunction

autocmd BufWritePre * call AddLastLine()
```

Comment: Works perfect! out of curiosity. the last line `autocmd BufWritePre * call AddLastLine()` means when saving all kinds of files right? how to customize this further to work only on/excluding specific filetypes. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Use `autocmd BufWritePre *.c\|*.cpp\|*.java\|*.py call AddLastLine()` but it will works only for specified extensions, you want filetypes so the better way is this `autocmd FileType c,cpp,java,python autocmd BufWritePre * call AddLastLine()`.